# how to set locales and keyboard layout in the command line without gui

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, debian, locale

I'd like to do a bash script that lets change the language of a debian based system by typing a number for each language. Sadly I'm not familiar with debconf.

How can I change the keyboard-layout and the language of the console permanently with debconf-selections

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work:

1. Install `console-data`
2. Configure it to your liking via `dpkg-reconfigure console-data`
3. Save the values via `debconf-get-selections | grep console-data > FILENAME`
4. Load these values from your script via `debconf-set-selections < FILENAME`

I guess there is a pattern to the `console-data` configuration debconf file, so after a few `dpkg-reconfigure` you might be able to construct your own.

Comment: Nice one. You would need to run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration -f noninteractive` after step 4.